# SO_BINDTODEVICE option support for FreeBSD

Tags: sockets, freebsd, raw-sockets

I am implemneting a code based on Raw sockets. In order to receive coming Ethernet frames I have to bind the socket I created to an Ethernet interface. The only way to do that, as far as I am concerned, is via setsockopt() function with the option SO_BINDTODEVICE.

The problem is that I am using FreeBSD which does not support such option. Is there any patch to use in order to enable this feature or any other trusted alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sendto` if you are working with IPv6, see [this example](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2004-February/002926.html).
Unfortunately this doesn't work with IPv4.

As antiduh said, you can use libpcap to capture packets, provided you have access to `/dev/bpf` (which is usually restricted to `root`).